# In Eclipse RCP is there a way to check if the help window is open?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I need to check if the current active window is the help window.
There is a `org.eclipse.ui.help.IWorkbenchHelpSystem.isContextHelpDisplayed()` method that checks whether the context sensitive help window is open but there doesn't seem to be a way to check if the standard help window is open.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Check this out.

```
IWorkbench workbench = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
IWorkbenchWindow activeWorkbenchWindow = workbench.getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
IWorkbenchPage activePage = activeWorkbenchWindow.getActivePage();
IViewReference[] viewReferences = activePage.getViewReferences();

for ( IViewReference iViewReference : viewReferences ) {
    if ( iViewReference.getId().equals( "org.eclipse.help.ui.HelpView" ) ) {
        // Yay, it's open!
    }
}
```